# Solving a special nonlinear program using fmincon()

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-optimization

My problem is the following optimization problem:

```
min J=X'*E*X+U'*E*U
s.t. X'- X0'-(X')*D1*Q*P+(X')*D1*Q*Z=0,
     I*I'*(D2')*U-Q*I=0
```

where `X` and `U` are `2*r+1 by 1` column matrices, `X0` is `2*r+1 by 1` known column matrix and `E, D1, D2, P and Z` are known `2*r+1 by 2*r+1` matrices and  `I` is a `2*r+1 by 1` known column matrix. Also, Q is a matrix which satisfied in
`I*I'*(D2')*U=Q*I`.

> Known matrices: `X0, E, D1, D2, Z,  P, I`

Thanks in advance.

## My try:

> Ojective function file name: **objective_function.m**

```
function objective = objective_function(Unknown,r, E) 
Unknown = ones(2*r+3, 2*r+1);
X = Unknown(1, :);
U = Unknown(2, :);
Q = Unknown(3:end, :);
objective = (X')*E*X +(U')*E*U;
end
```

> Constraint function file name: **constraint.m**

```
function [inequality, equality] = constraint(Unknown, r,  X0, Z, I, P, D1, D2)
Unknown = ones(2*r+3, 2*r+1);
X = Unknown(1, :);
U = Unknown(2, :);
Q = Unknown(3:end, :);
% No inequality constraint 
inequality = [];
equality = [X'- X0'-(X')*D1*Q*P+(X')*D1*Q*Z ; I*I'*(D2')*U-Q*I];
end
```

> Optimization file name: **main.m**

```
   clear all
    clc
    r=2;

    % X0
      X0(1)=1;
    for i=2:2*r+1
        X0(i)=0;
    end
    X0=X0';
    % P
    P1=[1/2];
    P2=zeros(1,r);
    for i=1:r
        P3(i)=(-1)/(i*pi);
    end
    P4=zeros(r,1);
    P5=zeros(r,r);
    for i=1:r
        V1(i)=1/(2*i*pi);
    end
    P6=diag(V1);
    for i=1:r
        W(i)=1/(2*i*pi);
    end
    P7=W';
    for i=1:r
        V2(i)=(-1)/(2*i*pi);
    end
    P8=diag(V2);
    P9=zeros(r,r);
    P=3*[P1 P2 P3 ; P4 P5 P6 ; P7 P8 P9];
    % D1
    M1=[1];
    M2=zeros(1,r);
    M3=zeros(1,r);
    M4=zeros(r,1);
    for i=1:r
        V4(i)=cos((2*i*pi)/3);
    end
    M5=diag(V4);
    for i=1:r
        V5(i)=sin((2*i*pi)/3);
    end
    M6=diag(V5);
    M7=zeros(r,1);
    for i=1:r
        V6(i)=-sin((2*i*pi)/3);
    end
    M8=diag(V6);
    for i=1:r
        V7(i)=cos((2*i*pi)/3);
    end
    M9=diag(V7);
    D1=[M1 M2 M3 ; M4 M5 M6 ; M7 M8 M9];
  
    % D2
    N1=[1];
    N2=zeros(1,r);
    N3=zeros(1,r);
    N4=zeros(r,1);
    for i=1:r
        VV4(i)=cos((2*i*pi*2)/3);
    end
    N5=diag(VV4);
    for i=1:r
        VV5(i)=sin((2*i*pi*2)/3);
    end
    N6=diag(VV5);
    N7=zeros(r,1);
    for i=1:r
        VV6(i)=-sin((2*i*pi*2)/3);
    end
    N8=diag(VV6);
    for i=1:r
        VV7(i)=cos((2*i*pi*2)/3);
    end
    N9=diag(VV7);
    D2=[N1 N2 N3 ; N4 N5 N6 ; N7 N8 N9];
   
    % Z
    Z1=[1];
    Z2=zeros(1,2*r);
    for i=1:r
        Z3(i)=(3/(2*i*pi))*sin((2*i*pi)/3);
    end
    Z3=Z3';
    Z4=zeros(r,2*r);
    for i=1:r
        Z5(i)=(3/(2*i*pi))*(1-cos((2*i*pi)/3));
    end
    Z5=Z5';
    Z6=zeros(r,2*r);
    Z=[Z1 Z2 ; Z3 Z4 ;Z5 Z6];

     % E
    V3(1)=2;
    for i=2:2*r+1
        V3(i)=1;
    end
    E=diag(V3);

    % PHi
     R1=@(x) arrayfun(@(i)cos(i*pi*x),1:r);
     R2=@(x) arrayfun(@(i)sin(i*pi*x),1:r);
     R = @(t) [1, R1(t), R2(t)];
     I=R(1);
     I=I';
     

     A=[];
    b=[];
    Aeq=[];
    beq=[];
    lb=[];
    ub=[];

      initial=ones(2*r+3, 2*r+1);
   
% Objective function
J =@(decision_variable)objective_function(decision_variable, r, E);

% Constraint
equality = @(decision_variable)constraint(decision_variable, r, X0, Z, I, P, D1, D2);



solution = fmincon(J,initial,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,equality);

% X and U extraction 
 X_sol = solution(1:2*r+1);
 U_sol = solution(2*r + 2:end);
```

Comment: what is your question? what you tried to do and what is wrong? is your program throwing some errors? What are the variables you are looking for in your optimization? What is Phi and where does it enter on your optimization problem? 
Also, it would be instructive if you could provide the actual mathematical problem you are trying to solve along with the code itself.

Comment: @Thales My variables are matrices `X` and `U`. Actually, I don't know how to define `Phi*Phi'*D2*U=Q*Phi` in the constraint section of the problem in which `Phi` is a function in `t` defined above. Can I define it this way:  `function [inequality, equality1,equality2] = constraint(input, r,  X0, E, D1, D2, Z, P, Phi)

X = input(1:2*r+1);
U = input(2*r+2:end);
% No inequality constraint 
inequality = [];
equality =  X'-X0'-X'*D1*Q*P+X'*D1*Q*Z=0; equality2=Phi*Phi'*D2*U-Q*Phi;

end`

Comment: @Adam Could you please help me about my problem?

Comment: @Adam I mean Phi = @(t) [1, Phi1(t), Phi2(t)]. I've edited above. We can put Phi=Phi(1). I've edited all mathematical background we need.

Comment: @Adam Yes, that's true.  Right now, I've written it. Instead of Phi(1), I wrote matrix I which is a `2*r+1 by 1`column matrix.

Comment: @Adam Sure. What you're saying is right. I'll try to do it. Thank you.

Comment: @Adam Could you please tell me how can I define `Q` as an input (`2*r+1 by 2*r+1 matrix`)?

Comment: @Adam I've updated my try by your information but unfortunately it didn't work. The error is "Error in main (line 128)
solution = fmincon(J,initial,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,equality);

Caused by:
    Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. FMINCON cannot continue.

Comment: @Adam Could you please help me? I can't really solve it. I don't know where I made a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`U` and `X` are column vector description is as follow for `r = 1`

```
X = [x11; x12; x13] --> X is 3 by 1

U = [u11; u12; u13] --> Y is 3 by 1

Q = [ q11 q12 q13; 
      q21 q22 q23; 
      q31 q32 q33] ---> Q is 3 by 3

Unknown = [ x11 x12 x13; 
            u11 u12 u13; 
            q11 q12 q13; 
            q21 q22 q23; 
            q31 q32 q33]--> Unknown is 5 by 3

Unknown(1, :) is [ x11 x12 x13] --> 1 by 3 --> X = transpose(Unknown(1, :))

% Variable identification
---> X = Unknown(1, :)'
---> U = Unknown(2, :)'
---> Q = Unknown(3:end, :)
```

> In `constraint.m` there is dimension issue while concatenating

```
equality = [equality1; equality2]

equality1 = X'-X0'-(X')*D1*Q*P+(X')*D1*Q*Z

equality1_dimension = 1*3-1*3-(1*3)*(3*3)*(3*3)*(3*3)+(1*3)*(3*3)*(3*3)*(3*3) = 1*3

equality2 = I*I'*(D2')*U-Q*I

equality2_dimension = (3*1)*(1*3)*(3*3)*(3*1) - (3*3)*(3*1) = 3*1
```

- The two equalities should have same number of columns.
- Just transpose one of them.

```
equality = [equality1; equality2']
```

In short update `constraint.m` and `objective_function.m` but read first to understand why.

> Ojective function file name: objective_function.m

```
function objective = objective_function(Unknown,r, E) 
X = Unknown(1, :)';
U = Unknown(2, :)';
Q = Unknown(3:end, :);
objective = (X')*E*X +(U')*E*U;
end
```

> Constraint function file name: constraint.m

```
function [inequality, equality] = constraint(Unknown, r,  X0, Z, I, P, D1, D2)
X = Unknown(1, :)';
U = Unknown(2, :)';
Q = Unknown(3:end, :);
% No inequality constraint 
inequality = [];
equality = [X'- X0'-(X')*D1*Q*P+(X')*D1*Q*Z ; (I*I'*(D2')*U-Q*I)'];
end
```

> main.m

```
clear all
    clc
    r=2;

    % X0
      X0(1)=1;
    for i=2:2*r+1
        X0(i)=0;
    end
    X0=X0';
    % P
    P1=[1/2];
    P2=zeros(1,r);
    for i=1:r
        P3(i)=(-1)/(i*pi);
    end
    P4=zeros(r,1);
    P5=zeros(r,r);
    for i=1:r
        V1(i)=1/(2*i*pi);
    end
    P6=diag(V1);
    for i=1:r
        W(i)=1/(2*i*pi);
    end
    P7=W';
    for i=1:r
        V2(i)=(-1)/(2*i*pi);
    end
    P8=diag(V2);
    P9=zeros(r,r);
    P=3*[P1 P2 P3 ; P4 P5 P6 ; P7 P8 P9];
    % D1
    M1=[1];
    M2=zeros(1,r);
    M3=zeros(1,r);
    M4=zeros(r,1);
    for i=1:r
        V4(i)=cos((2*i*pi)/3);
    end
    M5=diag(V4);
    for i=1:r
        V5(i)=sin((2*i*pi)/3);
    end
    M6=diag(V5);
    M7=zeros(r,1);
    for i=1:r
        V6(i)=-sin((2*i*pi)/3);
    end
    M8=diag(V6);
    for i=1:r
        V7(i)=cos((2*i*pi)/3);
    end
    M9=diag(V7);
    D1=[M1 M2 M3 ; M4 M5 M6 ; M7 M8 M9];

    % D2
    N1=[1];
    N2=zeros(1,r);
    N3=zeros(1,r);
    N4=zeros(r,1);
    for i=1:r
        VV4(i)=cos((2*i*pi*2)/3);
    end
    N5=diag(VV4);
    for i=1:r
        VV5(i)=sin((2*i*pi*2)/3);
    end
    N6=diag(VV5);
    N7=zeros(r,1);
    for i=1:r
        VV6(i)=-sin((2*i*pi*2)/3);
    end
    N8=diag(VV6);
    for i=1:r
        VV7(i)=cos((2*i*pi*2)/3);
    end
    N9=diag(VV7);
    D2=[N1 N2 N3 ; N4 N5 N6 ; N7 N8 N9];

    % Z
    Z1=[1];
    Z2=zeros(1,2*r);
    for i=1:r
        Z3(i)=(3/(2*i*pi))*sin((2*i*pi)/3);
    end
    Z3=Z3';
    Z4=zeros(r,2*r);
    for i=1:r
        Z5(i)=(3/(2*i*pi))*(1-cos((2*i*pi)/3));
    end
    Z5=Z5';
    Z6=zeros(r,2*r);
    Z=[Z1 Z2 ; Z3 Z4 ;Z5 Z6];

     % E
    V3(1)=2;
    for i=2:2*r+1
        V3(i)=1;
    end
    E=diag(V3);

    % PHi
     R1=@(x) arrayfun(@(i)cos(i*pi*x),1:r);
     R2=@(x) arrayfun(@(i)sin(i*pi*x),1:r);
     R = @(t) [1, R1(t), R2(t)];
     I=R(1);
     I=I';


     A=[];
    b=[];
    Aeq=[];
    beq=[];
    lb=[];
    ub=[];
% intial contains X, U and Q
initial = ones(2*r+3, 2*r+1);

% Objective function
J =@(decision_variable)objective_function(decision_variable, r, E);

% Constraint
equality = @(decision_variable)constraint(decision_variable, r, X0, Z, I, P, D1, D2);



solution = fmincon(J,initial,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,equality);

% X U and Q extraction 
 X_sol = solution(1, :)
 U_sol = solution(2, :)
 Q_sol = solution(3:end, :)
```

> Solution

```
X_sol =

    0.2905   -0.2881   -0.2905    0.3984   -0.2893


U_sol =

   -0.0097   -0.0097    0.0097    0.0167    0.0167


Q_sol =

    2.6741    6.1937    3.4713    1.9752    4.3157
    0.1062    0.7722    0.7143    0.4598    0.6802
    1.7584    3.6335    1.8268    0.7934    1.3207
   -1.2972   -3.2643   -1.9671    0.7630   -0.1526
    2.2088    5.4597    3.2508    1.3825    0.4301
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It works but the answer for both `X` and `U` are `[1,...,1]` and `[1,...,1]` which is not correct. I think it comes from `Unknown = ones(2*r+3, 2*r+1)`.

Comment: I defined `X = Unknown(1, 2*r+1)'; U = Unknown(2*r+2, 4*r+2)';` but I don't know how to define  `2*r+1 by 2*r+1` matrix `Q` as an input.

Comment: You're right. I asked a lot of questions and I've taken your time. You defined this way `Unknown = ones(2*r+3, 2*r+1); X = Unknown(1, :)'; U = Unknown(2, :)'; Q = Unknown(3:end, :);` but now you say remove `Unknown = ones(2*r+3, 2*r+1)`. I did it but it doesn't work. What do I do? This is my last question. Thank you very much.

Comment: I appreciate you very very much. I am so sorry to take your time a lot. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Your answer is great. Yes, of course I will. Thanks so much.